# Species of animals

Tags: questions, partitives

Which one is correct? Types of animals, kinds of animals or species of animals? Please write some examples. And is it correct to say "species of fish"?

Comment: They're all grammatical English phrases, but they don't mean the same thing. _Species_ is a taxonomical term with a very complex technical definition; if you don't know it, don't use it. _Kind_ and _type_ are non-specific about the taxonomy involved, so they can be used for any division into subsets.

Comment: This question has one VTC as opinion based, but it is most emphatically not opinion based as the comment of  Lawler and the excellent answer of @Sprog demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

John is correct. 'Type' and 'kind' can be used informally and interchangeably, pretty much any way you like.

Animals that eat fruit - that's a type or kind of animal.
Animals that live in deserts. Purple animals. Animals that are kept as pets. Animals that squeak. Animals with  scales. Animals that live in water - those are all types or kinds of animal.

Species is quite different. Species of animals are precisely defined by their evolutionary relationships and are internationally standardised by the International Commission on Zoological Nomenclature. Each species has a unique scientific name which is 'binomial' i.e. it has two parts.

A group of related species is called a genus. The binomial name of every species consists of the genus to which that species belongs, followed by the unique species descriptor.

For example Passer domesticus is the bird known in English as House Sparrow.
Passer means the genus of all sparrows. domesticus means house. Passer domesticus is a species.

Passer montanus is also a species (montanus) within the genus of Sparrows (Passer). In English this bird is called the Tree Sparrow even though its scientific name means Sparrow of the Mountains. In German the same species is called Feldsperling which means Field Sparrow. You can see how confusing it can get, and why the international standard binomial name for each species is so important and useful.

Defining a species is nowadays based on DNA but previously it could be quite complicated. The simplest species concept is that of reproductive isolation, which simply means that animals of the same species can reproduce with one another, animals of different species can't. In real life things aren't quite so simple, but that concept is sufficient for learning English. This isn't a science board!

Another useful English word with respect to animals is 'breed'. This is more useful than the vague terms 'type' or 'kind' because it has a precise meaning. In common usage, a breed of animal is a variation within a species that has been developed artificially by humans via selective breeding. For example Great Dane and Pekinese are breeds of dog, but Dog is a species. Shire and Arab are breeds of Horse, but Horse is a species.

I hope this makes sense! It's a simplified account of a pretty complex subject in biology, but again this is an English board, not a science board ;)